# Как убрать горизонтальную полосу прокрутки (scroll) для iframe

Tags: html, iframe

```
<div class="modal-window-content">
    <iframe src="about:blank" frameborder="0"  width="700" height="680" align="center" scrolling="auto">
</div>
```

В фрейм загружается страница сайта. Все попытки убрать горизонтальную прокрутку (разными способами) не дают результата. Укажите, в каком направлении копать.

Заранее Благодарю за любую подсказку (помощь).

Comment: w3school сайт смотрели? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: Если убрать то только обе.

Comment: Да уж... Робота...

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Всем Решение найдено

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; width:680px; height: 550px; border: solid 0px #dddddd">
<div style="overflow: auto; width:  680px; height: 750px;margin: -105 auto; ">
     
     <iframe  src="about:blank" width="680" height="750" bgcolor="#000000"  frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" 

allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always"></iframe>
     </div></div>
```